# How to add one NSArray data to another NSArray fields?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I tought question title is little bit mismatch , can you please see the following explanation...

Currently i am having 2 NSArray's of data:

```
 NSArray *arr1 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"aa",@"bb",@"1",@"cc", nil];

 NSArray *arr2 = @[self.lbl1, self.lbl2, self.lbl3, self.lbl4];
```

In **1st** Array i got data from server

I need to load those parameters in specific UILabel's in **2nd** Array

**I am looking O/P is**::

```
self.lbl1.text = @"aa";

self.lbl2.text = @"bb";

self.lbl3.text = @"1";

self.lbl4.text = @"cc";
```

Is there any possiblity, can you please help me out..

in **ViewController.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel* lbl1;
@property (strong, nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel* lbl2;
@property (strong, nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel* lbl3;
@property (strong, nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel* lbl4;
```

in **ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

NSArray *arr1 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"aa",@"bb",@"1",@"cc", nil];
NSArray *arr2 = @[self.lbl1, self.lbl2, self.lbl3, self.lbl4];

for(int i=0;(i<[arr1 count])&&(i<[arr2 count]);i++)
{
    UILabel *label = (UILabel*)[arr2 objectAtIndex:i];
    label.text = (NSString*)[arr1 objectAtIndex:i];
}
NSLog(@"%@,\n %@,\n %@, \n%@",self.lbl1,self.lbl2,self.lbl3,self.lbl4);
```

}

**CRASH** like:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
 *** First throw call stack:
```

Comment: store the labels in the arrays, not their text property.

Comment: If you don't mine can you please elabrate the answer @ ShahiM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the labels in the arrays, not their text property.

```
NSArray *arr1 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"aa",@"bb",@"1",@"cc", nil];
NSArray *arr2 = @[self.lbl1, self.lbl2, self.lbl3, self.lbl4];

for(int i=0;(i<[arr1 count])&&(i<[arr2 count]);i++)
{
  UILabel *label = (UILabel*)[arr2 objectAtIndex:i];
  label.text = (NSString*)[arr1 objectAtIndex:i];
}
```

Checking for count of both like : `(i<[arr1 count])&&(i<[arr2 count])` ensures that the app does not crash if somehow the arrays become of different count.

Comment: Sorry, I am getting crash on "arr2" like:: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'

Comment: are any of labl1, lbl2 .. etc having `nil` value?

Comment: put a breakpoint in the second line (`NSArray *arr2 = ....`) and check their values.

Comment: @MannamBrahmam please check if all the IBOutlets are properly connected. The issue is one of those labels is `nil`

Comment: try putting the NSLog as first line. it will print.

Comment: I checked already thrice but in my end it's connected perfectly, even tough i use like(strings)::  NSArray *arr2 = @[str1, str2, str3, str4]; ====> I am getting crash in same line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100467/discussion-between-mannam-brahmam-and-shahim).

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly do that but you can set `arr2` to:

```
arr2 = @[self.lbl1, self.lbl2, self.lbl3, self.lbl4];
```

and then

```
for (UILabel *lbl in arr2) {
    NSInteger i=[arr2 indexOfObject:lbl];
    lbl.text = [arr1 objectAtIndex:i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both arrays have the same size, you can do:

```
NSArray *arr3 = @[self.lbl1, self.lbl2, self.lbl3, self.lbl4];

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < arr1.count; i++) {
    arr3[i].text = arr1[i];
}
```

If the size of the array received from the server may vary, you can use `MIN(arr1.count, arr3.count)`, i.e. minimum of the two sizes, so you won't get an out-of-bounds exception:

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < MIN(arr1.count, arr3.count); i++) {
    arr3[i].text = arr1[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: It is Not possible the way you want to do it.

This is because `self.lbl1.text` is a NSString and not attached to `self.lbl1` anymore (`text` is a copy property of UILabel). If you change this NSString, you 
would not change the value of `self.lbl1.text`

A better approach may be to save only the label, not its value:

```
NSArray *arr2 = @[self.lbl1, self.lbl2, self.lbl3, self.lbl4];
```

In this case, you could loop through your array:

```
for (NSInteger i=0; i < arr2.count && i < arr1.count; i++) {
    ((UILabel*)[arr2 objectAtIndex:i]).text = [arr1 objectAtIndex:i];
}
```